# Creating json in specific format in java for android

Tags: java, android, json

I have a complex code in java which when simplified becomes as described below:

I create objects from 'myclass' class and add it to a `List<myclass>` object.

I convert the `List<myclass> to List<Map>` object.

Now I create a JSONArray and..

convert all Map objects in `List<Map>` to json object and then add them to jsonArray object.

Then finally I convert it to string with toString function.

```
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();
        for(Map m : map) {
            JSONObject mapjs = new JSONObject(m);
            arr.put(mapjs);
        }
        String mapString=arr.toString();
```

With this, I'm able to get a string as below..

```
[{"json1":{"id":"jsonid1"}},{"json2":{"id":"jsonid2"}}]
```

I need it to be in the following format..

```
{"json1":{"id":"jsonid1"},"json2":{"id":"jsonid2"}}
```

Sincerely appreciate all help..

Thanks

Comment: Why didn't you create a new JSONObject(), then add the other objects to it instead of using JSONArray()?

Comment: Then I guess it would create..{{"json1":{"id":"jsonid1"}},{"json2":{"id":"jsonid2"}}}, still not the format I need or am I wrong..

Comment: That is indeed the format you want, then you can access the entire string which is 1 JSON Object then select one of your inner json objects from that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better way seems to be to create a map in such a format which when converted to json creates the file in necessary format

```
Map mymap = new Hashmap();
    for(Map m : map) {
               mymap.putall(m);
            }
    JSONObject mapjs = new JSONObject(mymap).toString();
```

Comment: Thank you for posting an answer to this question! Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow, because a code dump with no context doesn't explain how or why the solution will work, making it difficult for the original poster (or any future readers) to understand the logic behind it. Please, edit your question and include an explanation of your code so that others can benefit from your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The square braces indicates the json data inside is an array so instead of putting your data using `JSONArray` just use the `JSONObject`

```
JSONObject arr = new JSONObject();
int i = 1;
for(Map m : map) {
   JSONObject mapjs = new JSONObject(m);
   arr.put("json"+i, mapjs);
   i++;
}
String mapString=arr.toString();
```

Comment: I do not get the option of adding arr.put(mapjs); JSONObject does not have an option to put another JSONObject

Comment: @Arnab .. Oh sorry about that, updated the answer and it should give the desired results

Answer (score 0):

To put another JSONObject into a JSONObject, you can try as the following:

`JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject().put("json1", new JSONObject.put("id", "jsonid1"));`